# How did the Greek word "oikonomia" get the meaning of "thrift"?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, ancient-greek

Some dictionaries seem to include the word "thrift" at the end of the definition for *oikonomia*. I found some good examples [on the Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/economy) and [on Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economy):

> Greek oikonomia "household management, thrift.

I would like to know the source of this meaning, as it seems that *oikonomos* is directly understood as only household management.

When and how did the word "economy" start to mean a **thrift** household management?

Comment: Can we know this meaning is not a later influence of its meaning in another language? E.g. that it first got it from English (or Latin), and was then adopted by modern Greek as a meaning? I bet this is what happened in Spanish, where the word _economia_ can also means thrift.

Comment: @luchonacho Good thought, but LSJ also includes "thrift", citing several classical authors.

Comment: How? I think the semantic shift is pretty obvious.

Comment: @Draconis. It might be useful, if anyone has the time, to look up the references in LSJ and determine whether any of them really requires the meaning "thrifty house-keeping".

Comment: The correct term would be a **metonymic** (semantic) change or shift. While it’s very easy to envision such a change, I’m not entirely sure if it happened in Ancient Greek. Let’s look at some examples.

Comment: I'd concur with @Alex B.   "Management, oversight, administration, of property" obviously entails care with preservation of resources. It happened in Ancient Greece.